# The greatest area for a rectangle on a track field.

Tags: quadratics

An athletic field with a perimeter of 0.25 miles consists of a rectangle with a semicircle at each end, as shown below. Find the dimensions that yield the greatest possible area for the rectangular region.

This is the work that I did below. I was wondering if this was the greatest possible area for the rectangle below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Near the end of page $1$, you wrote $r=\frac{2}{16\pi}$ when you meant to say $2r=\frac{2}{16\pi}$
- Once we found out that $r=\frac{1}{16\pi}$, we can compute $$l=\frac18 - \pi r= \frac18 -\frac1{16}=\frac1{16}$$ directly without finding $A$ explicitly.

Comment: why would it be 2r?

Comment: you wrote $r=\frac2{16\pi}$ and then you wrote $w=\frac{1}{8\pi}$?

Comment: I got r to equal 1/16pi. I then multiplied this by 2 because of 2r=w. I then got 1/8pi for w.

Comment: Great, do not write $r = \frac1{16\pi} \times 2$, you can write $r \times 2 = \frac1{16\pi} \times 2$ or $2r = \frac1{16\pi} \times 2$.

Comment: so the 'l' and the 'w' are still correct?

Comment: yup, just a minor (but very crucial in the long run) writing issue and longer working, it's fine.